# Finding in navigation history, should I use $.mobile.navigate.history.closest?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I find the function `$.mobile.navigate.history.closest` available, but cannot find how to use it.  Is there any documentation?

I am looking for such a solution:
pages are all `[data-role=page]`,
in which some (but not all) are root pages `[data-my-role=root]`
as navigating through many pages, a click on a button will go to the last root page.

`$.mobile.navigate.history.closest(some_criteria)` seems good for finding this last root page, but I don't know the syntax of `some_criteria`

Comment: you want to navigate back to closest page with `data-role=root`?

Comment: @Omar  I want to navigate back to closest `<div data-role="page" data-my-role="root">`.

Answer (score 0):

[`$.mobile.navigate.history.closest`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/js/navigation/history.js#L90-L119) searches for an entry either by `id` or `url`. You can create a custom function to loop through history entries `$.mobile.navigate.history.stack` and look for specific data.

Note that if you want to alter navigation and to determine navigation direction, you need to use `pagecontainerbeforechange` event - only when it returns `string` not `object`.

The below code loops (in reverse) through history entries and checks whether that entry has `data-my-root="true"` - `.data("my-root")`. This custom `data` is added to root pages.

```
$(document).on("pagecontainerbeforechange", function (e, data) {

    if (typeof data.toPage == "string" && data.options.direction == "back") {
        var i, active = $.mobile.navigate.history.activeIndex;
        /* loop through history entries in reversed order */
        for (i = active; i >= 0; i--) {
            /* to avoid errors, "i" shouldn't equal 0
               history entry shouldn't be current page */
            if (i != 0 && $($.mobile.navigate.history.stack[i].hash).data("my-root") && !$($.mobile.navigate.history.stack[i].hash).hasClass("ui-page-active")) {
                /* alter page */
                data.toPage = $.mobile.navigate.history.stack[i].url;
                /* optional */
                data.options.transition = "flip";
                break;
              /* means first page is reached - there's no hash for first page 
                 move to first page */
            } else if (i === 0) {
                data.toPage = $.mobile.navigate.history.stack[0].url;
                data.options.transition = "flow";
            }
        }
    }
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/cduvjbkj/)**

Comment: seems ok with 'Root Page 2' and 3, but once clicking on the *black-background* 'Root Page 1' then going to 2 and 3, the back button does nothing when clicked.  Let me study more.  Thanks.

Comment: This solution changes all back actions.  Actually I need to have both  'normal back' and 'root back' buttons -- only 'root back' jumps to the root page.  Any idea how to do so?

Comment: @KaFaiLo simply, add `!data.prevPage.data("my-root")` condition to `if` statement. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/cduvjbkj/

Comment: I am not sure, but this seems not what is needed.  What I need is:  navigation history is [1,2,3,4],  only 2 being a root page.  On 4 two buttons are shown *on the same page*: 'normal back' and 'root back' buttons.  'Normal back' goes to 3, 'root back' goes to 2.

Comment: @KaFaiLo you can add listeners to those buttons and use the code above instead of listening to `pagecontainerbeforechange`. I gave you an idea how to hijack back navigation, all you need is to modify it to your needs. I dont have your code, so I can't predict what you want to achieve 100%. If you provide me with fiddle with your page structure, I'll be happy to help you further.

Comment: I see, I will try to apply the above to button click events.